# organization chart jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to create organization chart page, that allow the user to:

1. Write node name in a text field.
2. Drag and drop the text field to a specific location in the hierarchy DIV.
3. Remove or update hierarchy(change node name or remove it).

After a quick search on the internet I found [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) and [google code](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html).  The problem in InfoVis Toolkit that it uses HTML5 and I need HTML4.

Is there is any other organization chart jquery plugin that satisfies the requirements?

Comment: I made this one using Jit js: https://github.com/rlopez0689/OrgChartJit

Answer (score 5):

Check out Google Chart Tools http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html It's pure Javascript and not JQuery tough, but we use it and it works ok.